# I have imported memberships, need memberships to count as contributions

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, import

I have imported memberships tied to households via CSV, but have just realized that despite the fact I uploaded the membership type and payment amounts are saved for each membership type, no associated contribution record has been created. In other words, the membership appears in a  contact's record with the correct start and end date, etc., but when I pull by contributions or look at a contact's contribution record, there is nothing.

How might I go about fixing this? I need contributions to inherit membership purchases.

Thank you!

Ahna K

Answer (score 4):

Do a .csv import of new Contributions of financial type Member Dues, Civi ID, contribution amount, contribution date for each, then export that list with Internal Contact ID, and create a list of new or updated (a separate import for each) Memberships to import.